# JSON.net linq can not select node with where statement

Tags: asp.net, json, linq, json.net

I'm trying to select the node where empUID equals a certain ID. Here is my JSON snippet

```
{
    "dsShedule": {
        "ttEmployee": [
            {
                "empUID": 2649,
                "empNameFirst": "Firstname",
                "empNameLast": "lastName",
                "empFunction": "AFWERKER DRUKKERIJ",
                "ttShedule": [
                    {
                        "UID": 47,
                        "empUID": 2649,
                        "datStart": "2013-05-20",
                        "datStop": "2013-05-20",
                        "regime": 1,
                        "state": "PLANNED",
                        "ttSheduleDay": [
                            {
                                "SheduleUID": 47,
                                "dat": "2013-05-20",
                                "dateTimeStart": "2013-05-20T08:00:00.000",
                                "dateTimeStop": "2013-05-20T17:00:00.000",
                                "duration": 8
                            }
                        ]
                    },
                    {
                        "UID": 57,
                        "empUID": 2649,
                        "datStart": "2013-05-21",
                        "datStop": "2013-05-21",
                        "regime": 1,
                        "state": "PLANNED",
                        "ttSheduleDay": [
                            {
                                "SheduleUID": 57,
                                "dat": "2013-05-21",
                                "dateTimeStart": "2013-05-21T08:00:00.000",
                                "dateTimeStop": "2013-05-21T17:00:00.000",
                                "duration": 8
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                ]
            },
```

I'm able to select all the employee nodes but the moment I try to select the node where the ID equals for example 494323, it can not be found.

### The function

```
        JObject jObj = JObject.Parse(json);
        int firstUID = 494323;
        var linq = jObj["dsShedule"]["ttEmployee"].Select(x => new
                        {
                            empUID = x.SelectToken("empUID"),
                            empNameFirst = x.SelectToken("empNameFirst"),
                            empNameLast = x.SelectToken("empNameLast"),
                            ttShedule = x.SelectToken("ttShedule")
                        });
        var uid = linq.Where(x => x.empUID.Equals(firstUID));
```

I'm using VS2012 and when I debug the element linq and look for the value of empUID, it shows the value {494323} (Why the brackets?).

Below a picture of the variables:

[image]

As you can see uid is empty, what am I missing?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You select not the values in your select query but JToken objects:

```
empUID = x.SelectToken("empUID")
```

empUID is of type JToken (you can see the type in the debug view). 
Then you try to compare an integer to a JToken which will fail.

Just select the values like this:

```
empUID = x.SelectToken("empUID").Value<int>()
```

Or use `Value<T>` when comparing:

```
var uid = linq.Where(x => x.empUID.Value<int>() == firstUID);
```

**EDIT**

Im not sure what you exactly want, but this should give you an idea.

1. Filter the ttEmployee array for the first entry with the given empUID
2. Select the ttShedule array of that entry
3. Filter with `Where` all ttSchedule entries, that contain a ttSheduleDay with a dat property of a given value:

   ```
   var linq = jObj["dsShedule"]["ttEmployee"]
            // first filter for a single emp by empUID
            .First(emp => emp["empUID"].Value<int>() == firstUID)
            // then select the ttShedule array of that emp
            .Select(emp => emp["ttShedule"])
            // now filter for whatever ttShedule you need
            .Where(shed => shed["ttSheduleDay"]
                         .Any(day => day["dat"].Value<DateTime>() 
                                                == new DateTime(2013, 5, 24))
   ```

Comment: The variable UID is now an employee. Now I would like to select the "datStart" that is under ttShedule from that variable UID. How can I select this? It's like an IEnumerablelist of <JToken> at this time, don't know how to handle it.

Comment: `ttShedule` is an array. Do you want to get all `datStart` values or the first, the last, ...

Comment: What I'm trying to accomplish is to select the ttSheduleDay dateTimeStart. But this where the empUID equals = 'an ID' and where ttSheduleDay > dat equals a date. Then I got a third parameter with Start / Stop or duration and this will determine what node I will select. How should I do this? Thx 4 answering

Comment: I'm breaking down the code u gave me to fully understand it, because it doesn't do anything at this moment. I replaced the select of ttShedule with SelectToken, because the select didn't worked. So now I have my ttShedule selected but I busy finding out how I can execute the where statement... I will probably open a new question and post the link here

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16730454/complex-linq-nested-where-statements-json-net-and-linq